# Как рендерить страницу с якорем в Django?

Tags: django

Уважаемые разработчики Django, подскажите, пожалуйста, как во view сделать рендер страницы, чтобы она открылась по якорю (в определенном месте)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3036307/1891712